# Why my express session not deleting/destroying when clicking on logout?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, express-session

Once I logged in, I can't able to logout because the express-session is not deleting, to logout I have to manually delete the session collection from mongo which is a separate collection with user and post for full code you can also look for https://github.com/roshantak44/nodejs-blog-tutorial

> //controllers/logout.js

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy()
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

> //middleware/auth.js

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
User.findById(req.session.userId, (error, user) => {
    if (error || !user) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
})
```

}

> //middleware/redirectIfAuthenticated.js

```
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
if (req.session.userId) {
    return res.redirect('/');
}

next()
}
```

> //app.edge

```
<!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>      
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>      
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>         
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts/new">New Post</a></li>
                 @if(!auth)

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>          
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>
                 @else

        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>         
                 @endif
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>  
@!section('content')
<!-- Footer-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.session.destroy(function(err) {
    response.redirect('/');
});
```

Maybe you should try like this!

Comment: Maybe this code can work inside of function write this => req.logout();

Comment: already tried that but didn't work can you please check my repo on above mentioned link